# Centos 7 pecl install mysqlnd_azure failed to install

Tags: centos, azure, pecl

In Centos 7.9 with PHP - 7.4 enr,

I want to install below Pear Extension

https://pecl.php.net/package/mysqlnd_azure/1.1.1

However When i run below to install it gives me that package is not found.

Any reason why it doesn't recognise the package?

```
[root@a-1 ~]# pecl install mysqlnd_azure

No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mysqlnd_azure"
install failed
```

Comment: You might need to enable the repo. Consult this link under **SETUP**: https://github.com/microsoft/mysqlnd_azure

Comment: @JohnHanley repos is enabled, i can install other pecl extensions without any issue.